# Swift - Empty NSMutableDictionary or NSDictionary? Optional

Tags: swift, dictionary

Just curious, in Swift, is it more ideal to initialize an empty NSMutableDictionary variable, `NSMutableDictionary = [:]`, and later re-assign its value to a new dictionary (coming from an API for example),

OR, is it better to declare an optional NSDictionary, `NSDictionary?` and assign it to a new dictionary?

Comment: It's better to use a Swift `Dictionary` over `NS(Mutable)Dictionary`. And optionality completely depends on whether you want to be able to tell the difference between "no response" and "empty response".

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your needs, do you want it to be nil sometimes? is it nil sometimes? 
If an array is always gonna have value, even if it's an empty value, I personally like to Initialize it right away, and not hassle with unwrapping everywhere.

Maybe if you had two arrays, one was normal array, and the second one was a searched result. You might wanna check if searched result is nil first, if it is, show the array1, if it isn't show it instead.

And this is implying you only search "sometimes", thus that array is only sometimes used - so you might as well have that deallocated when not in use, if you aren't using it most of the time.

EDIT: I've been using arrays in my example, but same applies for a dictionary in those situations.
EDIT: In Swift It's best to avoid 'NS' classes, sometimes you have to use them, sure. But Swift's Dictionary does the job.

Example:

```
var sometimesUselessDict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?
var alwaysUsedDictionary = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

So with Swift it would technically be best practice to use a Dictionary type. Like this for example:

```
var dict: Dictionary<String, Int>
```

If you need the dictionary as a whole to be able to be nil use an optional.

Answer (score 0):

You should make it optional only if you need to be able to distinguish a dictionary that's empty from one that doesn't exist at all.  For instance, if you're receiving data from a server, you might want to distinguish between a successful response that returned no data (empty dictionary) and a failed or invalid response (nil).

If that distinction isn't important, I would always go with a non-optional to avoid unnecessary unwrapping.